# How to add second email account to Geary?

Tags: geary, email-client

When I try to add a second email account to my Geary (version 0.8.3 on Ubuntu 15.04), the 'Add' button of the account dialogue window remains inactive. Despite having filled in all required fields. Any ideas?

[image]

Unfortunately, I have a localized version installed (German). Hence, I don't know the exact button names of the English form. However, you can see the button `Hinzufuegen`, which says 'Add'. This very button is not clickable but remains inactive.

Comment: It might help if you post a screenshot of the screen you are talking about. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/623166/edit) your question and add the screenshot (or a link to the screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like already one year ago - but I could have the solution, because I had the same problem: Type in both the passwords, else the "Hinzufügen"-Button (Add) will not be activated.

Hope that helps at least other guys who googles this.

Answer (score 0):

The nickname field is required but does not give a visual indication that it is.

Try putting something in the nickname field and see if the Add button appears.